# How to Group Applications at Build Time

Tags: android

Being a bit new to android and compiling my own images for my device, I was trying to figure out how to do the below in the source code directly.

How can one group applications in folders on the home screen at build time when building/compiling the device image?

Follow-on question to this, how can one configure the apps that appear in the home screen bottom row?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not really done at build time, but you need to update the launcher xml configuration panels to state which apps you want and in there you can also create a subfolder to regroup applications.